# jQuery Click Handler with Called Ajax Sub-Method has a strange delay on $(this).prop('disabled', true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a strange situation where the following Click-Handler (via `one()` to prevent double-clicks) has a called Ajax method from the inside. The first thing it's supposed to do is to disable my button.

Normally, if I don't have any Ajax inside and just have a simple click handler, this works and disables the button immediately:

```
 $('#button').one('click', function (event) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
 });
```

But if I have the following, with a called sub-method which involves Ajax, I notice that the 1st statement (Disable Button) **does not** occur until the sub-method is complete. But why? The button should  get disabled immeditely as the first statement, regardless of how long the Ajax takes to complete.

```
 $('#submitButton').one('click', function (event) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true); // Doesn't get disabled until AFTER submitSurvey()
    submitSurvey();  // Call some method that does Ajax
 });     

 function submitSurvey() {
     $.ajax({
            url: 'surveyProcess',
            type: 'post',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            async:   false,  /* Note async = false, so nothing asynchronous here either */
            success: function() {   
                //...    
 }
```

What could be going on here? I just need to disable the button immediately, without any delay.

Comment: It's because you're using `async: false` which blocks the browser from updating the UI while the request is in progress. Don't do that.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the call to submitSurvey() ? If you get no dlay then it verifies that the code in submitSurvey is blocking the current code. You can either make it async true, or if you cannot do it for whatever reason call the submitSurvey() after a short delay using setTimeout().

Comment: Thanks, Rory's comment was the solution. I didn't realize that even the UI operations were being blocked, or that simple disabling would take a longer time than the subsequent Ajax. After I removed `async: false` it worked. Thanks again

Comment: @geneb. never ever EVER even think about doing synchronous http requests in javascript again. there's a reason why the browser warns you not to do it. it blocks the main thread. never ever ever do this again. don't even consider it. Not wanting to be rude, but you need to understand that this is a cardinal sin, and why they haven't removed it yet is a mystery but it will be removed eventually.

Comment: @r3wt it's not been removed for two reasons. Firstly there are some valid cases for its use (eg. sending an AJAX request in `beforeunload` needs to be sync to stop the browser closing before the request completes) and secondly for backwards compatibility. Similar to `eval()`, there are valid cases for its existence but 99% of the time it's abused.

Comment: Can someone tell me, why is the Disable step not complete well before the Ajax begins? I understand the UI locking, but it seems to me the Disable is an instantaneous atomic flip, so it should be guaranteed to complete before anything that follows. Regardless of the evils of `async=false` -- the UI should be done prior to that point.

Answer (score -1):

You can use beforeSend() event for the same use

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'surveyProcess',
        type: 'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        async:   false,  /* Note async = false, so nothing asynchronous here either */
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        },
        success: function() {   
            //...  
        }
    });
 });
```